# RGB или HUE палитра на сайте

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Как сделать квадрат рядом с которым будет три скроллбара к которыми можно привязать RGB или HSV значение цвета этого квадрата. Можно ли это сделать на чистом css и как это сделать при помощи JavaScript? Очень надеюсь на ваш отклик. Я новичок js ещё не изучал.

Comment: @Алексей, похоже это он и имел ввиду=)

Comment: @Arthur Спасибо) Такой хороший сайт, даже часа не прошло)

Comment: @AleksVolkoV, обращайтесь, но помните, здесь любят качественные вопросы, в которых есть свои попытки(код) и наглядный пример того, что вы хотите получить.

Answer (score 2):

На скорую руку получилось вот такой колорпикер.

```js
var r = 0;
var g = 0;
var b = 0;
$('input[name=r]').on('input', function(){
 r = $(this).val();
  $('.color').css('background-color', 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
  $('output').val('rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
});

$('input[name=g]').on('input', function(){
 g = $(this).val();
  $('.color').css('background-color', 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
   $('output').val('rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
});

$('input[name=b]').on('input', function(){
 b = $(this).val();
  $('.color').css('background-color', 'rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
   $('output').val('rgb('+r+','+g+','+b+')');
});
```

```css
.color{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=color></div>
<output></output> <br>
<input class='rgb' type="range" name='r' min='0' max='255' value ='0'> red <br>
<input class='rgb' type="range" name='g' min='0' max='255' value ='0'> green <br>
<input class='rgb' type="range"  name='b' min='0' max='255' value ='0'> blue
```

Answer (score 1):

Признаюсь, `JS` не мой — [ссылка](https://codepen.io/leemark/pen/lpEHr?editors=1010)

```js
var r = document.getElementById('r');
var g = document.getElementById('g');
var b = document.getElementById('b');
var r_out = document.getElementById('r_out');
var g_out = document.getElementById('g_out');
var b_out = document.getElementById('b_out');

function setColor() {
  var r_hex = parseInt(r.value, 10).toString(16);
  var g_hex = parseInt(g.value, 10).toString(16);
  var b_hex = parseInt(b.value, 10).toString(16);
  var hex = "#" + pad(r_hex) + pad(g_hex) + pad(b_hex);
  document.getElementById('block_output').style.backgroundColor = hex;
}

function pad(n) {
  return (n.length < 2) ? "0" + n : n;
}

r.addEventListener('change', function() {
  setColor();
  r_out.value = r.value;
}, false);

r.addEventListener('input', function() {
  setColor();
  r_out.value = r.value;
}, false);

g.addEventListener('change', function() {
  setColor();
  g_out.value = g.value;
}, false);

g.addEventListener('input', function() {
  setColor();
  g_out.value = g.value;
}, false);

b.addEventListener('change', function() {
  setColor();
  b_out.value = b.value;
}, false);

b.addEventListener('input', function() {
  setColor();
  b_out.value = b.value;
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div:not(#block_output) {
  text-align: center;
}

#block_output {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}

label,
output {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    <label for="r">R</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="r" step="1" value="0">
    <output for="r" id="r_out">0</output>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="g">G</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="g" step="1" value="0">
    <output for="g" id="g_out">0</output>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="b">B</label>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="255" id="b" step="1" value="0">
    <output for="b" id="b_out">0</output>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="block_output"></div>
```